# Getting the list of file names already loaded in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, backbone.js, widget

I have come across a situation where I need to check whether a file is already loaded into the DOM so that I should not load it again. 
Actually I have a scenario in which there are many small projects which are hosted on the same domain but all have their resources like jquery, backbone.js etc. (**Wookie Widgets**).

**Question is: Can I get the list of names of the files that are already loaded into the DOM?**

P.S:  I need to get the list of the javascript files loaded into the DOM and I am not looking for any workaround. Please let me know any way to get all the list of the file NAMES... loaded into the DOM

Comment: The resources of the projects are copied in all of them as all of them are using jquery, backbone etc

Comment: Depending upon the type of resource, it's probably easier to test for the existence of something in the resource to see if it exists.  For example, you can check to see if the symbol `jQuery` exists to see if jQuery is already loaded.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yes, this can happen and I have already done it.. But our requirement is to look for file names in the DOM and then if it exists then we need to skip it otherwise load it. BTW thanks for the answer Friend

Comment: But "why" is that a requirement, when it's not the best way to do things?  jQuery can go by many different filenames depending upon how it was loaded.  Checking for the existence of jQuery itself is way more reliable than checking for the existence of a script tag with one particular jQuery filename.

Comment: @FaizanMustansar you need to clarify your question. Checking whether a file is already loaded and looking for the file name are two different things.

Comment: OK. Christophe: Let me clarify: My question is that I need to get the list of the javascript files loaded into the DOM and I am not looking for the workaround. Please let me know any way to get all the list of the file NAMES... loaded into the DOM

Comment: The question has been edited. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
$('script').each(function(){
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mdp9J/) is a example in fiddle.

Comment: @Maleeenc: My scenario is a bit different... Let me know that will it work if the script is loaded by some other project? deployed on the same domain? Let me check it as well ... I guess it will not..

Comment: Actually I am loading the contents of some other pages of a different project on the divs of a project and this solution is not working in my case. All of the projects are hosted by the same server

Comment: Actually you can use use this, if you are adding contents of a different project to a div. (I changed the fiddle accordingly) But i don't think that you can prevent any file from downloading, since you need to have prior knowledge about the content that is going to download. I think best way is parent page shouldn't have any non specific resources it self and let the divs handle themselves

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to use a script loader. See some examples here:
http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/essential-javascript-top-five-script-loaders-8122862

This will give you full control on the scripts you want to load and their dependencies.

If you just want to use script tags, you could attach onload event handlers to each tag.

Or you could poll the page to check for the existence of the object the script is supposed to load (e.g. window.jQuery).